# Bluetooth connection fakeout

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio

I have a Nexus 6 running Nougat. I've always had it connected to my car speakers via Bluetooth. Last night, I hit play on my music app, and although the car's display screen showed the song info and the progress timer, and I was able to navigate through my playlist (i.e. the car thought it was playing), the sound came from the phone.

I thought it was an issue with the car's connection, but then today I tried to connect my bluetooth earbuds, which have worked fine in the past. The phone's bluetooth settings showed that the earbuds were paired, and the buds gave me the little beep tone to indicate pairing, but again, when I hit play, the sound came blasting out the phone speaker, rather than through the earbuds.

I've tried unpairing and setting up from scratch, and that doesn't seem to make a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try [Sounds out](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix) - it is said to deal with sound routing problems very well

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but am still having the same problem.

Comment: Back up data and factory reset - drastic , yes

Comment: Not worth it. I'm just waiting for the next generation of Pixels to be released. I can do without my bluetooth music until then.